# Concurrent table creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a situation when table can be created from different places.
So, I have ~10 working applications, that can simultaneously try to create a same table. 
Question. How can I synchronize them ? So I don't have any exceptions or errors ?

All instances of the application are trying to create a new table when the day ends, so when there is something like 00:00:00 they all will try to create it.

Sorry, for possible 'stupid question', have been googling for a while, no results.
Thank you.

Comment: Why not make sure that doesn't happen.  Maybe append something unique to the front of the table name based on what application is trying to create the table.  ie, app1MyTable, app2MyTable, app3MyTable and etc.

Comment: You see, all 10 of them are instances of one application, and they all write logs in that table, so it would be great to see all logs from all servers in one place

Comment: Or before creating the table do a check to make sure it doesn't already exist...

Comment: Checking the existence does not prevent from simultaneous creation. Imagine that 2 threads checked the existence of the table at the same time and both passed forward ...

Comment: Then lock before create. also - how likely is it that you would have, at the precise time, 1 of your 10 apps create the table?

Comment: The thing is that we create a new table for logs every day, so when the time goes something like 00:00:00 they all can try to create a new table. How can I do this lock ?

Comment: So stagger the creation a little - even by half a second. There are a whole bunch of ways this issue can be worked around. Perhaps edit your questions with all the ways you have tried/failed and additional information - such as every day they create (which is pretty important....)

Comment: @Erik.Martirosyan why do you create a new log table every day? This seems like a very poor design. Surely you just need to add a datetime column to your log table to indicate when the record was created?

Comment: @gvee, you see, we have something like 100 GB of logs every day ... And keep logs only for last 3 days ... And we have column CreationDate and CreationTime :)

Comment: I fail to see how creating new tables will solve your problem. Consider a partitioned index? If you only keep 3 days then just have a  nightly job to purge anything older.

Comment: Better off backing up/archiving the day and starting a new one - your still taking up buckets load of disk space, new tables or not.

Comment: Maybe Darren and gvee you both are right, and the solution can be improved, the thing is that this design exists for 2 years already, and it is actually working without synchronization (there is just a transaction with serializable isolation level) I just wanted to find out how else this situation can be handled.

Comment: If you have 100 GB of logs every day, you are logging too much.  How can anyone find anything meaningful in that much data?

Comment: @cadrell0 well, we do :) We have reports and if user have problems we can easily understand the reason with logs. There is something like 5 million requests per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) to take arbitrary locks. You could make your app take such a lock before creating the table. Like that:

```
exec sp_getapplock
if tabledoesnotexist
 create table ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the comments, your first step is to perform an existence check. Then, on the off chance that there are two simultaneous creations you can use [TRY...CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx).

```
IF Object_ID('test', 'U') IS NULL
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
      CREATE TABLE test ( a int )
    END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT Error_Message()
      END CATCH
  END
```

---

## UPDATE

You **do not** want to create a table every day. Seriously. This is very poor database design.

Instead you want to add a `datetime` column to your table that indicates when each record was created.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please go through the following code ... Concurrent execution is handled using `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`.

```
     CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextID](
            @IDName nvarchar(255)
        )
        AS
        BEGIN
            /*
                Description:    Increments and returns the LastID value from tblIDs
                for a given IDName
                Author:         Max Vernon
                Date:           2012-07-19
            */

            DECLARE @Retry int;
            DECLARE @EN int, @ES int, @ET int;
            SET @Retry = 5;
            DECLARE @NewID int;
            SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            WHILE @Retry > 0
            BEGIN
                BEGIN TRY
                    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                    SET @NewID = COALESCE((SELECT LastID FROM tblIDs WHERE IDName = @IDName),0)+1;
                    IF (SELECT COUNT(IDName) FROM tblIDs WHERE IDName = @IDName) = 0 
                        INSERT INTO tblIDs (IDName, LastID) VALUES (@IDName, @NewID)
                    ELSE
                        UPDATE tblIDs SET LastID = @NewID WHERE IDName = @IDName;
                    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
                    SET @Retry = -2; /* no need to retry since the operation completed */
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    IF (ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205) /* DEADLOCK */
                        SET @Retry = @Retry - 1;
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                        SET @Retry = -1;
                        SET @EN = ERROR_NUMBER();
                        SET @ES = ERROR_SEVERITY();
                        SET @ET = ERROR_STATE()
                        RAISERROR (@EN,@ES,@ET);
                        END
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END CATCH
            END
            IF @Retry = 0 /* must have deadlock'd 5 times. */
            BEGIN
                SET @EN = 1205;
                SET @ES = 13;
                SET @ET = 1
                RAISERROR (@EN,@ES,@ET);
            END
            ELSE
                SELECT @NewID AS NewID;
        END
        GO
```